# Combine three table using access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables:

```
1. user    => user_id[Pk], user_name
2. payment => payment_id[PK], user_id[FK], amount
3. receive => receive_id[PK], user_id[FK], amount
```

Now I want to fetch record like:

**username, paymentamount,receivableamount**

Thanks in advance..

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175227/combine-three-tables-in-ms-access-2003), but it does not work for me.

Suppose, In user table

user_id   user_name
1             ABC
2             XYZ

In payment table

payment_id   user_id   amount
1                   1            1000
2                   1            200
3                   2           150

In receive table :
receive_id  user_id  amount
1                2            100
2                1            200

Now I want record like

user_name  paymentamount  receivableamount
ABC            1000                    200
ABC            200
XYZ            150                      100

Comment: are you expecting to be able to match payment_id and receive_id? If so, you are probably better off actually including a payment_id in your receive table as a foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to sum up amounts by user_id.

```
SELECT
    user.user_id,
    SUM(payment.amount) AS payment_amount,
    SUM(receive.amount) AS receive_amount
FROM (receive INNER JOIN [user] ON receive.user_id = user.user_id)
              INNER JOIN payment ON user.user_id = payment.user_id
GROUP BY user.user_id;
```

Comment: This is the only one so far that will run in MS Access.

Comment: For this to happen, you need an extra column (foreign key) in receive table to identify the payment_id. Then you need to add payment_id to the select, and change the join sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in query designer. Drag the three tables into it, link up the keys (drag and drop the fields onto each other), double click the fields you want to add them to the field list at the bottom, and then run the query.  Choose aggregate expressions if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to adapt this to MSAccess syntax but the idea is to perform a `LEFT JOIN` of payment and receive tables with user as that is the parent table and the other two tables may or may not have a record for this user.

```
SELECT 
    u.user_name, 
    ISNULL(p.amount, 0) as paymentamount,
    ISNULL(r.amount, 0) as receivableamount
FROM 
    user u
    LEFT JOIN payment p
    ON u.user_id = p.user_id
    LEFT JOIN receive r
    ON u.user_id = r.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    user.user_name, payment.amount, receive.amount 
from user 
    join payment on user.user_id == payment.user_id 
    join receive on user.user_id = receive.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.user_name, t2.amount payementamount, t3.amount receiveableamount from 
User t1,
payment t2,
receive t3
where
t1.user_id=t2.user_id and
t1.user_id=t3.user_id
```

> You can try this out....